What is this small flush mounted light in my home's ceiling?
I have a couple of these on my home's ceiling - one near the kitchen and one in a hallway. I assumed they were hard-wired smoke alarms, but I went to test them today (by pressing the white button on the left) and nothing happened. That said, the LED (on the right) does occasionally blink, so I know it has power.
Can anyone confirm what it is? Should I be concerned that the white button does nothing?


emergency lighting

The label suggests it's a Cold Cathode Discharge light bulb, and the lack of response likely means there's a long-since-dead rechargeable battery (lead acid?) in the ceiling - and/or a dead bulb  - or both. However from this view it could be a simple halogen bulb and some odd labeling, too.

@Ecnerwal No. The “C0 C90 D20” has no connection to “CCD” (fluorescent). The terms specify the emergency lighting beam shape. https://lenalighting.com/company/knowledge-base/1803-light-distribution
